# Verificar si archivo existe - antes de copiarlo/moverlo - a otra carpeta

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Windows Forms - Framework 3.5 - donde el usuario debe seleccionar dos (2) carpetas:

- **`Carpeta origen`**: La carpeta que tiene los archivos a pasar a la *carpeta destino*.
- **`Carpeta destino`** Carpeta que recibirá los archivos seleccionados por el usuario.

Tengo un **`ListBox`** donde listo los nombres de los archivos de la "carpeta origen", pero, necesito que - antes de agregar el **`item`** en el **`ListBox`**, verifique si el archivo existe en la **carpeta destino**.

La manera en que logro este objetivo es con el siguiente código:

```
// Limpio los ítems: 
lstBx_originFiles.Items.Clear();

// Instancias de las carpetas origen y destino seleccionadas: 
DirectoryInfo dirInfo_originFolder = new DirectoryInfo(fbd_originFolder.SelectedPath);
DirectoryInfo dirInfo_destinyFolder = new DirectoryInfo(fbd_destinyFolder.SelectedPath);

// Obtener solamente archivos con extensión ".mp3": 
FileInfo[] fi_originFolderFiles = dirInfo_originFolder.GetFiles("*.mp3");
FileInfo[] fi_destinyFolderFiles = dirInfo_destinyFolder.GetFiles("*.mp3");

// Recorrer los archivos de la carpeta origen: 
foreach (FileInfo fileOriginInfo in fi_originFolderFiles)
{
    // Agregar el archivo a la lista de selección "solo si no existe" 
    // Estos son los archivos que NO existen en la carpeta destino: 
    if (fi_destinyFolderFiles.Count(x => x.Name.Equals(fileOriginInfo.Name)) == 0)
    {
        lstBx_originFiles.Items.Add(fileOriginInfo.FullName);
    }
}
```

Me parece que la siguiente línea:

```
if (fi_destinyFolderFiles.Count(x => x.Name.Equals(fileOriginInfo.Name)) == 0)
```

No tengo evidencia, pero, como se lee la línea, me parece que no es muy eficiente.

¿Hay una manera más fácil o lo estoy manejando bien en este punto?

Comment: Deja ver si te entiendo, tu codigo funciona, lo que quieres es saber si funciona de manera optima?

Comment: Debieras tener en cuenta que si hay un archivo con el mismo nombre en destino, no significa que sea el mismo. Debes cuidar no sobreescribir, o pedir confirmación. Piensa en la posibilidad de comparar mediante funciones resumen.

Comment: @Japv, si, es correcto, es que usé `File.Exists(fileOriginInfo.Name)`, pero, me parece que la manera en que la estoy haciendo es "menos" eficiente.

Comment: Bueno mira ver lo q te puse y me dices

Comment: @quevedo ¿puedes colocar un ejemplo de "funciones resumen"?

Comment: Hola debes consultar [ComputeHash(Stream)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.computehash?view=net-5.0#System_Security_Cryptography_HashAlgorithm_ComputeHash_System_IO_Stream_). En los ejemplos, lo usan para calcular el hash de los archivos de un directorio. **Nota:** Dos archivos se pueden considerar iguales si producen el mismo hash. Es más puedes guardarlo en una columna de la tabla de archivos, (si la usas) para validar si ha habido modificaciones.

Comment: @quevedo la documentación dice que aplica para .NET 5.0 - yo estoy en 3.5. Es válido su apunte sobre validar los archivos, pero, por ahora, lo dejaré como pendiente. Gracias por las observaciones.

Answer (score 2):

```
var OriginalesQueNoExistenEnDestino = fi_originFolderFiles.Select(f => f.Name).Except(fi_destinyFolderFiles.Select(f2 => f2.Name)).ToList();
```

Podrías intentar esto, obtienes mediante el **operador de conjunto Except** los ficheros originales que no existen en el destino, haciendo la comparación por el nombre de los ficheros, al final se devolverá una línea con los ficheros de origen que no existen en el destino.

De esta forma te ahorras escribir el **foreach** y la condición, **Except** representa una resta de conjuntos C = A - B, en C se guardarán los elementos que están en A pero que no existen en B, A - B no necesariamente tiene que ser igual a B - A.

Atendiendo a lo nuevo que planteas en tu comentario prueba esto:

```
var OriginalesQueNoExistenEnDestino = (from f in fi_originFolderFiles
                                       where fi_destinyFolderFiles.
                                       Count(f2 => f2.Name == f.Name) == 0
                                       select f).ToList();
```

De esta forma recorres todos los ficheros originales y preguntas si el nombre de este coincide con el nombre de los ficheros de destino y cuenta la cantidad de coincidencias que hay, en caso de ser **0** quiere decir que ese fichero de la ruta original no está en el destino, por último se devuelve una lista de elementos de tipo **FileInfo**.

En el código mostrado hacemos uso de **Linq** por tanto debemos poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: El resultado de `fi_originFolderFiles.Select[...]` es un `List<string>`, ¿es posible obtener el listado como `FileInfo[]`? - su solución me parece mejor que la mía, pero la verdad sí necesito que el resultado del filtro sea `FileInfo[]`.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave revisa lo nuevo que puse y me dices